# Spring Security login after session expiration redirects to last JSF ajax request and displays its <partial-response> XML response like plain text

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, spring-security, partial-response

I'm working with a project that use Spring Security, Spring bean, JSF, PrimeFaces and Hibernate in combination.

In the homepage, I use poll to automatically get newest data after every 10 seconds.

```
<h:form>
    <p:poll interval="10"
            listener="#{mailBean.refreshMail}"
            update=":list-email"/>
</h:form>
```

The problem is after I log-in to the homepage, I open the homepage in another tab and in that tab, I click log-out and it redirect to the log-in page.

Even though the session ends, poll will continue to send ajax request and get response after every 10 seconds.

Then I wait some seconds and click log-in again to go to the homepage but this time it shows the XML content which is the partial response of the Poll.

[Here is the image link:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MB2u4.png) [image]

If I refresh the page, it becomes normal again.
I don't know why it render view like that.

I've spent a lot of time trying to solve this problem but I couldn't.
Please help me out. Thank you.

Comment: @BalusC, thank you for making my question more concrete. Do you have any solutions for this problem? Have you ever encountered it before?

Comment: I do understand the problem, but I have no idea how to solve it as I don't do Spring Security.

Comment: Does it have anything to do with Restore View phase? Why JSF renders XML instead of html?

Comment: Nope. Security frameworks usually redirect to last request after login. That last request was in your case a JSF ajax request (which has, obviously, a response in XML format). Basically, you need to tell Spring Security to not do that, but instead redirect to last synchronous request.

Comment: @BalusC, you saved me. That's the root cause for this error. Thank you a million.

Answer (score 2):

As Mr. BalusC said, Spring Security will redirect to last request after login. Because I used Poll so the it makes ajax request to the homepage after 10 seconds and when I login again, it will redirect to the ajax request.

So to solve this, I config in the security xml file as following, so that it will always redirect to the default page after login.

```
<form-login 
    login-page="/login.html"
    authentication-failure-url="/login.html?status=LOGIN_FAILURE"
    default-target-url="/index.html"
    always-use-default-target="true" />
```

Thank you so much, Mr. BalusC.