# JSF ajax response displayed plain vanilla in browser screen after redirect

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, spring-security, partial-response

I am working on a JSF application which redirect to another application then do some processing there and redirect back. Issue is when I use JSF application URL as

```
http://172.20.1.175:8080/app_path/page.xhtml
```

and redirect back to the URL,

```
http://172.20.1.175:8080/app_path/page1.xhtml
```

then I am getting xml page on the browser like following

```
<partial-response>
<changes>
<update id="javax.faces.ViewState">
<![CDATA[
-------
]]>
<![CDATA[
--------
]]>
</update>
</changes>
</partial-response>
```

but if I use http://localhost:8080/app_path/page.xhtml and redirect back to the URL http://172.20.1.175:8080/app_path/page1.xhtml it's working fine (172.20.1.175 is my IP address). I am using spring security for authorization.

I am trying to figure out the reason for this behavior. Any ideas?

Thanks,
Lakmal

Comment: How you redirect? What code you have written?

Comment: First invalidate the session `FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().invalidateSession();` then `ExternalContext ec = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();   ec.redirect(url)`

Comment: Ok..How `localhost` converted to ip address ?

Comment: My PC on a local network so 172.20.1.175 is my machine IP

Comment: Do u mean localhost converted to your ip adress i am right?

Comment: Yes, In configurations other application use my IP to redirect back

Comment: Do you mean  there are two different applications? If so you didnt mention this ? So you are redirecting some external context?

Comment: Yes, I did (redirect to another application) above, it's an external application and then back.

Comment: Then try this Solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5092439/redirect-to-external-url-in-jsf

Comment: I tried [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12504131/viewexpiredexception-not-thrown-on-ajax-request-if-jsf-page-is-protected-by-j-se) also, but I am always getting originalURL as null.

Comment: @SubodhJoshi I am already using that method to redirect to external application

Comment: I tried removing `FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().invalidateSession()` then it's working fine

Comment: @BalusC do you have any idea about this?

Comment: I don't do Spring, but the symptom is similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28317891, so that is perhaps helpful.